# Use BeautifulSoup to get text with different delimiters for each tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, data-science, html-parsing, text-processing

I want to use BeautifulSoup to get the text from an HTML string. While `get_text()`'s separator argument is nice, I would like to use different separators for different tags (or not use any at all for others).

As an example, consider the HTML:

```
<p>This is some paragraph text. With a <a href="example.com">link</a>.</p>
<div>This is another paragraph.</div>
```

Dummy code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

string = '<p>This is some paragraph text. With a <a href="example.com">link</a>.</p>\n<div>This is another paragraph.</div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(string)
text = soup.get_text('\n', strip=True)
print(text)
```

Using `get_text('\n')` outputs

```
This is some paragraph text. With a 
link
.
This is another paragraph.
```

But the desired output would be

```
This is some paragraph text. With a link.
This is another paragraph.
```

Is there a way to use `get_text()` and use the '\n' string as a separator for most tags and no separators for "inline" tags like `<a>` or `<b>`?

Note that the HTML I am parsing is not consistent so I can't use a function that corrects this behavior afterwards.

EDIT:
The reason for using a separator as an argument in `get_text()` is that the input is not guaranteed to have a newline between the two paragraphs.

If the example HTML was

```
<p>This is some paragraph text. With a <a href="example.com">link</a>.</p><div>This is another paragraph.</div>
```

the output still has to have the contents of `<p>` tags separated somehow.

EDIT 2:
Added different tags to the examples.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

string =  '<p>This is some paragraph text. With a <a href="example.com">link</a>.</p>\n<p>This is another paragraph.</p>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(string, "html.parser")
print(soup.getText())
```

Output:

```
This is some paragraph text. With a link.
This is another paragraph.
```

EDIT:

Try this for both strings:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

string_1 = '<p>This is some paragraph text. With a <a href="example.com">link</a>.</p>\n<p>This is another paragraph.</p>'
string_2 = '<p>This is some paragraph text. With a <a href="example.com">link</a>.</p><p>This is another paragraph.</p>'

soup = [p.getText().strip() for p in BeautifulSoup(string_2, "html.parser").find_all("p")]
print("\n".join(soup))
```

In both cases it should produce:

```
This is some paragraph text. With a link.
This is another paragraph.
```

Comment: This does not "work" if the input html string does not always have the `\n`. In that case the output would not separate the paragraphs at all, which is why I have to use the separator argument in `get_text()` in the first place.

Comment: Well, this is what you gave us in your [mre]. The changes I've suggested give you the desired outcome. Please provide a sample where the code doesn't produce the expected result.

Comment: I edited my question with one such example.

Comment: I mention in my question that the `<p>` tag is just an example, it has to work for everything all tags that`get_text()` checks. In other words your recommendation is to write my own version of `get_text()` that uses a delimiter only for the desirable tags?

Comment: I only work with what you give me. I doubt you'd be able to find a generic solution for *all tags* with an input that's not guaranteed.

Comment: Yeah the example was too simplistic but the question does not only contain code. Anyways, thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you all elements, separated, as list elements - and you can then choose/slice/separate/ do stuff to them later:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<p>This is some paragraph text. With a <a href="example.com">link</a>.</p>\n<p>This is another paragraph.</p>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print([x.get_text() for x in soup.find_all() if len(x.text) > 0])
```

Result in terminal:

```
['This is some paragraph text. With a link.', 'link', 'This is another paragraph.']
```

This is nothing special, nor dramatically different from baduker's response. My suspicion is - your question is in fact an XY problem, so it would be better if you could explain your end goal, as well as confirming the url you are trying to scrape. Also, BeautifulSoup documentation might help: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: I didn't go into specifics about my end goal, because it's about the "meaning" of the text. I wan't to split the text in a way that "makes sense". Of course since I can't exactly explain (neither to you nor to the computer) what does this mean, I abstracted it by specifying delimiters for "different tags". In my example, it "makes sense" that when an `<a>` tag is part of a bigger block of text, it's content should be inline with the rest of the text,  rather than separate. I am not trying to scrape a URL, but rather parse the HTML contents of emails.

Comment: In your proposed solution, there is no way to know that "link" was once part of an `<a>` tag, and thus it does not need a newline separator. And if there were more inline tags like ` <a href="example.com"><b>bold</b>link</a>`, the output list would contain "boldlink" too in the output (as a separate element from the `<a>` tag and the word "boldlink" as part of the `<p>` tag.

Comment: @liakoyras try replacing `find_all()` with `contents`. You'd then get the link as part of the parent element.

Comment: Oh, and @liakoyras: regaridng text meaning, there are other tools within NLP sphere to use: Spacy, Flair, transformers with HuggingFace models, etc.

Comment: I think your `.contents` suggestion might have helped me device something that while not perfect, is a better alternative to what I am currently doing. I' ll post it as an answer if I manage to make it work. As for the suggestions, thanks, these might be useful after I am done preprocessing. I am using nltk for some of these tasks, but I might need to use named entity recognition and it's nice to find frameworks that do it.